# Installing firefox using Ubuntu Live Media

Tags: 16.04, package-management

My firefox is uninstalled. I have Live Ubuntu System. I want to install it using the Live CD/USB. How can I do this?

Comment: I've edited your question. Check if it what you intended

Answer (score 0):

If you've Ubuntu Live CD/USB, you can get the firefox package from that Live System and install it.

Here is the process.

1. You need `dpkg-repack` for this. Install it with

   ```
   sudo apt install dpkg-repack
   ```
2. If your Live System is an .iso file, you can mount it. If it is a USB, it will be mounted automatically. For iso, the command to mount is

   ```
   sudo mount /path-to-your-ubuntu.iso /mnt
   ```

   It will mount the ISO in `/mnt` directory. If you media is a USB, you'll find the contents of it in directory with path like this `/media/tonmoy/USB-drive-name`.
3. Now you need to mount the `filesystem.squashfs` file which actually contains the Live System. I'm assuming, your ISO or USB is mounted in `/mnt` for simplicity.

   Mount the `filesystem.squashfs` using this command

   1. First make a temporary directory

      ```
        mkdir ~/tmp
      ```
   2. mount the `squashfs` file

      ```
        sudo mount /mnt/casper/filesystem.squash ~/tmp
      ```

   It will mount the live system in the `tmp` folder in your home directory.
4. Repack the firefox .deb file. Use this command to extract and re-build firefox from the live system

   ```
   sudo dpkg-repack --root=/home/tonmoy/tmp firefox
   ```

   I've assumed that your username is tonmoy. Replace it with actual username

   You'll see messages like this while building

   ```
   dpkg-deb: building package 'firefox' in './firefox_45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb'.
   ```
5. Then now install repacked firefox .deb file using dpkg

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i firefox_45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```

It should install the firefox in the system. Now unmount the filesystem.squashfs for being safe (optional)

```
 sudo umount /home/tonmoy/tmp
```

Hope that helps.